# Cannot access to remote sitecolletion

Tags: 2013, site-collection, internet

I have created a site collection, after that added Internet Zone in Alternative mapping, but still cannot access to this site collection.

I have a suggestion to enter login/pass, but it is not accepted :(

**EDIT:**

While creating a site collection I could access to the site, but when operation has been completed I received "401 UNAUTHORIZED".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check DNS settings, IIS bindings for your site?

Comment: Could you tell me what DNS and IIS Settings should I check?

Comment: Maybe this can help you. [social.technet.microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/sharepointadminprevious/thread/f5a54a9a-96fe-4af9-ae81-37b8de7a975e) and [support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)

Answer (score 0):

After Creating Site Collection you have to add up Site Collection Administrators. Have you added it?

Thanks.

Comment: I've checked, it was added. I can access to the site collection on the local computer, but cannot access from a remote PC.

Answer (score 0):

Verify [loopback check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861) is disabled or configured properly.